# Can Apple's Numbers spreadsheet link to a Mathematica function?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, command-line, spreadsheets, interoperability

I use Apple's Numbers spreadsheet for a single thing, a double entry accounting model to understand complicated financial transactions.

A current model depends on the value of a single initialization cell.  I calculate this value in Mathematica using `Solve[]` as Numbers can't solve a system of equations.  Currently I have to manually input this value in the Number's spreadsheet.

Ideally I'd like the cell in Number's to call the Mathematica function.

Does any means exist to do this?

Excel/Link or Math/Link would appear to provide functionality similar to this, but reading through their respective documentation doesn't provide any clear way to do this with Numbers.

I can write command-line code to do this (generally):

```
$ MathKernel -script file.m
```

which suggests that AppleScript or some other scripting language could do this if callable/runnable from Numbers.

Perhaps all of this suggests a better or more general question: What means exist, if any, for calling a Mathematica function or script from applications outside of Excel or specifically applications programmed for J/Link or Math/Link?

Comment: I don't have Numbers but if you can use AppleScript to do things in Numbers then you can run the script from Mathematica